# confused about a build pattern c#

Tags: c#

I have am little confused with implementing an object oriented programming in my game I hope you can help me out.

so I created:

1. `ChunkClass`: base class for chunk objects
2. `ChunkBuilder`: a factory static class which produces chunks
3. `Map`: class which positions my chunks, items, scenery objects etc..

My `ChunkBuilder` class as follows:

```
public static class ChunkBuilder
{
    private static List<Chunk> _chunk = new List<Chunk>();

    public static List<Chunk> Chunk
    {
        get { return _chunk; }
        set { _chunk = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a chunk with tiles on position.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tx">Tiles on the X Axis.</param>
    /// <param name="ty">Tiles on the Y Axis.</param>
    /// <param name="tz">Tiles on the Z Axis.</param>
    /// <param name="pos">The Posiiont of the Chunk.</param>
    public static void CreateChunk(int tx, int ty, int tz, Vector3Int pos)
    {
        _chunk.Add(new Chunk(tx, ty, tz, pos));
    }
}
```

I think I am doing the wrong way creating chunks like that, because that way I am getting the chunk data from a list in the `ChunkBuilder`...but that seems to me wrong because, that is suppose to be building class? Also in that same `ChunkBuilder` class I wanted to add a method `RemoveChunkFrom(Vector3Int pos)` and this will totaly destroy the build pattern? I admit I am programming from 4 months now and I am confused about how is the proper way of doing such a thing. Can you help me out?

Comment: Why are you saving them in a `List`?

Comment: I am saving them in list because the Chunk class itself contains an array of [struct of Tiles] which contains some position data, collision info etc.

Comment: So you have the same data in two places? Try writing the calling code first (or maybe some unit tests) to avoid messes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `ChunkBuilder.CreateChunk` method return the newly created chunk after adding it to the list.

As for how it feels.. perhaps a naming change will help.. `ChunkBuilder` could become `ChunkFactory`.

Comment: As long as it isn't `ChunkSuppository`  ;-)

Comment: Yes that's what i needed..it feels way more natural for the Chunks to stay in the Map class.Thank you it was so obvious, but i didn't managed to think of it..Sorry i can't vote it useful its just my first post

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing

```
public static void CreateChunk(int tx, int ty, int tz, Vector3Int pos)
{
    _chunk.Add(new Chunk(tx, ty, tz, pos));
}
```

to

```
public static Chunk CreateChunk(int tx, int ty, int tz, Vector3Int pos)  
{
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(tx, ty, tz, pos);
    _chunk.Add(chunk);
    return chunk;
}
```

The calling code can then use the new `Chunk` rather than ask for the list and try to look up the new item.

Now, why is the data being kept in a `List`? If you add a method to remove an item, the "Builder" class isn't just a builder class. You need to think of a better name which describes what it does.

Comment: I believe this is the same answer as Dan's but it's the right for me..Neither way i can't still vote :D